# Set an v-play app type to show fullscreen

Tags: android, qml, qt-quick, v-play

How can I show my v-play (a qt quick extension) "app" type as a fullscreen app in all platforms and specially in android?
my main.cpp code:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
VPApplication vplay;
vplay.setPreservePlatformFonts(true);
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
vplay.initialize(&engine);
vplay.setMainQmlFileName(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/Main.qml"));
QtWebView::initialize();
engine.load(QUrl(vplay.mainQmlFileName()));
```

my main.qml code:

```
import VPlayApps 1.0
import QtQuick 2.0
App {
     id: app
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
App {
    id: app
    onInitTheme: {
        Theme.colors.statusBarStyle = Theme.colors.statusBarStyleHidden
    }
}
```

hope this helpful to you  :)